# Synchronous Execution in Javascript app

Tags: javascript, ajax, synchronous

I'm writing a js app that is tracking movement of devices. The user is able to select from a list of devices which ones to track on a map. The displayed device ID is different than the ID reported by the device to the tracking database, so I need to do a lookup of displayed device ID to actual device ID.

I'm using ajax to query the database, but I need it function synchronously, the app needs to wait until the actual device IDs are returned until it then starts to track location by those IDs. I know we're not supposed to make ajax calls with async set to false, and I haven't been able to get wait/async to function where execution is blocked until the device IDs are returned in the ajax.done callback.

What is the best practice for this situation?

Thanks...

Comment: You put the code to start tracking in `done`.

Answer (score 0):

use promises to wait for response.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise